# Is the order of $ab^{-1}$ larger than $m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $F$ be a field, $a,b\in F^*$, the order  of $a$ is $m$, the order of $b$ is $n$, $m>n>1$, $n\nmid m$ and $(m,n)>1$. Is the order of $ab^{-1}$ larger than $m$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F=\Bbb Z/31\Bbb Z$, $g$ the generator of $F^*$, $a=g^2, b=g^{-3}$.